When is a polynomial over a finite field divisible by $1+x+\ldots+x^{n-1}$?
Recently I read about a theorem in a book, which goes as follows:
Theorem. Let $n$ be a positive integer and $(a_i)_{i=0}^{n-1}$ a sequence of non-negative integers. We define the polynomial
$$P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{a_i}.$$
If the terms of the sequence $(a_i)$ form a complete residue system modulo $n$, then
$$Q(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{i}$$
is a divisor of $P$.
When we consider polynomials over $\mathbb{C}[x]$, this is relatively easy to prove by just looking at the $n$-th roots of unitys.
My question: Are there related results for polynomials over finite fields?

The same divisibility result holds over any field. A simple way to see that is to obseve that
$$Q(x)\mid (x-1)Q(x)=x^n-1\mid x^{kn}-1$$
for all $k\in\Bbb{N}$. Consequently $Q(x)\mid x^A-x^B$ whenever $A\equiv B\pmod n$. Meaning that you can replace $a_i$ with its remainder modulo $n$.

The above idea is the same used here for $n=3$. Check out Bill Dubuque's answer. In the last part he explains the general case. Observe that the method does not require roots of unity.

One last comment. Roots of unity do reside in extensions of finite fields. That's because every non-zero element of every finite field is a root of unity! The notable complication is that in characteristic $p$ no $p$th roots of unity can exist, because $x^p-1=(x-1)^p$. Consequently no $m$th roots either whenever $p\mid m$.

All, I realize that even though the idea for the solution is in that post by Bill D, some may find it a stretch to call this a duplicate. If you feel that some aspects haven't been dissected there (or possibly elsewhere), I'm open to other opinions. This kind of closure decisions are reversible for a reason :-)

See the method of simpler multiples in the 2nd dupe for generalizations. Could you please cite the result you mention (what book, and what theorem / chapter / page)?

There is no need to restrict to finite fields. Polynomial divisibilities  in $,\Bbb Z[x],$ are universal - they map into every ring since the equation witnessing the divisibility persists in every ring (by the universal property of polynomial rings), e.g. by the first dupe, in $,\Bbb Z[x],$ we have $,x^2+x+1\mid x^{14}+x^2+1,$ so $,x^{14}+x^2+1 = (x^2+x+1)f(x),\ f(x)\in \Bbb Z[x].,$ This equation persists to be true when we evaluate it at $,x=r,$ for $,r,$ in any ring $,R.\ \ $

Beware that we need to restrict to commutative target rings if we allow more general polynomials than those in $,\Bbb Z[x],,$ since then the polynomial arithmetic may depend on commutativity, e.g. $,xy = yx,$ or $,\alpha x = x\alpha,,$ which need not remain true after evaluation into a noncommutative ring. $\ \ $
